# Taxes on returning a signing bonus

Tags: united-states, taxes, bonus, income-tax

I received a signing bonus from a company for 3k, unfortunately I won't be joining them after I graduate so I need to return it.

I was deposited a total of 2.2k after taxes, however when I asked about how to return the bonus they said they need a check for 2.6k.

I understand that something was withheld for taxes, but I don't understand how this is calculated. What is the 0.4k that I did not receive? Also, what is the 0.4k that I owe them? What will I receive in my tax refund?

Can someone explain this scenario?

Comment: What country are you talking about?

Comment: I'm in the United States

Comment: If there was already withholding, there was a payroll statement or stub. Since you'll never be on their intranet ask them for a paper or electronic copy.